# Nextjs 14 and @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr overlapping query issue

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-client, next.js13, react-apollo

I am using next.js 14 and apollo experimental lib, i am using suspense with useSuspenseQuery, when i reload page it always fire query in browser side even if query run on server also.
https://prnt.sc/53bLQGLYgNhH -- query running on server
https://prnt.sc/Ban7QSSzg-IQ -- query running on browser
due to each time query running on browser also it showing loading status of suspend each time.

Main RSC component

```html
import Paragraph from "@/ui/Paragraph";
import Breadcrumb from "@/components/breadcrumb";
import Heading from "@/ui/Heading";
import CategoriesLinkWithScroll from "@/ui/categorieslinkwithscroll";
import CategoryLink from "@/ui/categorylink";
import ErrorBoundary from "@/components/errorboundary";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import CategoryCards from "@/components/bingocardcategorypage/categorycards";

export default function CardCategoryPage({
    pageData,
    ageGroups,
    cardDifficulties,
}) {
    const title = pageData?.name;
    const description = pageData?.description;
    const breadcrumbs = pageData?.seo?.breadcrumbs;
    const breadcrumbTitle = pageData?.seo?.breadcrumbTitle;
    const childrenCategories = pageData?.children?.nodes;
    const databaseId = pageData?.databaseId;

    return (
        <>
            <section className="py-4 lg:py-6">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="mb-3 lg:mb-6">
                        <Breadcrumb
                            breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}
                            breadcrumbTitle={breadcrumbTitle}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <Heading level="h1" className="h1 font-recoleta mb-4">
                        {title}
                    </Heading>
                    <Paragraph className="sub-title sm:max-w-600px">
                        {description}
                    </Paragraph>
                    <CategoriesLinkWithScroll className="mt-4 md:mt-6">
                        {childrenCategories?.length > 0 &&
                            childrenCategories.map((category, index) => (
                                <CategoryLink
                                    key={`cloud_${index}`}
                                    label={category?.name}
                                    uri={category?.uri}
                                />
                            ))}
                    </CategoriesLinkWithScroll>
                </div>
            </section>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>....loading</div>}>
                    <CategoryCards
                        termId={databaseId}
                        ageGroups={ageGroups}
                        cardDifficulties={cardDifficulties}
                    />
                </Suspense>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </>
    );
}
```

Cards Compoennt

```html
"use client";

import CategoryFilter from "@/components/categoryfilter";
import BlogReletedPostCard from "@/components/blogreletedpostcard";

import { useSuspenseQuery } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import GET_TEMPLATEBY_CATEGORY from "@lib/queries/wordpress/GET_TEMPLATEBY_CATEGORY";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { siteUrls } from "@/utils/constant";

const gridSizesOptions = [
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "9", label: "9" },
];

export default function CategoryCards({ termId, ageGroups, cardDifficulties }) {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const perPage = 12;

    const agegroup = searchParams.get("agegroup");
    const gridsize = searchParams.get("gridsize");
    const difficulty = searchParams.get("difficulty");

    const variables = {
        first: perPage,
        cardCategories: `${termId}`,
    };

    if (agegroup) {
        variables.ageGroups = agegroup;
    }
    if (gridsize) {
        variables.cardGrid = gridsize;
    }
    if (difficulty) {
        variables.cardDifficulty = difficulty;
    }

    const { data } = useSuspenseQuery(GET_TEMPLATEBY_CATEGORY, {
        variables: variables,
        fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    });

    const ageGroupOptions = ageGroups
        ? ageGroups?.nodes.map((ageGroup) => {
              return { label: ageGroup.name, value: ageGroup.databaseId };
          })
        : [];

    const cardDifficultiesOptions = cardDifficulties
        ? cardDifficulties?.nodes.map((cardDifficulty) => {
              return {
                  label: cardDifficulty.name,
                  value: cardDifficulty.databaseId,
              };
          })
        : [];

    const Cards = data?.bingoCards?.edges
        ? data.Cards.edges.map((edge) => edge.node)
        : [];

    return (
        <section className="pt-4 pb-7 lg:pt-6 lg:pb-60px">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
                    <div className="hidden gap-4 lg:flex">
                        <CategoryFilter
                            options={ageGroupOptions}
                            labelText="Age Group"
                            name="agegroup"
                        />
                        <CategoryFilter
                            options={cardDifficultiesOptions}
                            labelText="Difficulty"
                            name="difficulty"
                        />
                        <CategoryFilter
                            options={gridSizesOptions}
                            labelText="Grid Sizes"
                            name="gridsize"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => setOpenfilter(true)}
                        className="flex items-center justify-center order-2 w-8 h-8 rounded-lg border border-solid border-gray-200 p-1.5 text-gray-600 lg:hidden"
                    >
                        <i className="bcc-filter" />
                    </button>
                    <span className="text-xs font-medium text-primary-800 rounded bg-primary-50 py-1 px-2 lg:text-sm">
                        56 cards
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul className="grid gap-8 grid-cols-1 py-6 not-prose lg:grid-cols-4">
                    {Cards.map((card, index) => {
                        const cardImage = card?.cardImage
                            ? JSON.parse(card.cardImage)
                            : undefined;
                        const imageUrl = cardImage
                            ? siteUrls.cardImage(card?.cardId, cardImage?.value)
                            : "";

                        return (
                            <BlogReletedPostCard
                                key={card?.databaseId || index}
                                tag="li"
                                cardUrl={card?.uri}
                                cardImageSrc={imageUrl}
                                cardImageAltText={card?.title}
                                cardImageWidth="284"
                                cardImageHeight="284"
                                cardTitle={card?.title}
                                ageGroup={card?.ageGroups?.nodes}
                                cardDificulties={card?.cardDifficulties?.nodes}
                                isShownBadge={true}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
                <button className="btn btn-primary w-full mx-auto px-5 mt-0 lg:mt-6 lg:w-auto">
                    Load more
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

apollo client setup i have done same as per apollo doc here - https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/frontend/using-apollo-client-with-next-js-13-releasing-an-official-library-to-support-the-app-router/

Comment: That seems correct. If you can provide us with a reproduction at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs/issues, I can take a look.

Comment: @phry Hi i am able to find the issue in code, its weird but seems in apollo client provider code where i have added cache function before: https://prnt.sc/ugeW2nhmjDZ4 and after:  https://prnt.sc/zET5mvcMULwr , in after you can see i have directly put NextSSRInMemoryCache inside makeclient, after trail and error i find this, i am not sure about this but this resolve issue.

Comment: Ah yes, your initial code shared one cache between all users and the new setup doesn't. Never use global variables in Next.js, they will be shared between all requests in SSR!